# Is there a html5 API for video element that can trigger event at given playing cue?

Tags: html

I'm try to implement caption display in html5, something like:

```
video_element.addEventListener('CUE=11ms',show_sub1,false)
```

how can I do this? and besides popcorn.js is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 `<video>`, or all HTML5 media elements, have **timeupdate** event you should use for such purposes.

https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice/blob/master/src/show.js#L953

More info:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!mdn+timeupdate

Comment: timeupdate is what I want, the there is no research result in the link you posted

Comment: Yes there is :) Seems it's AJAX loaded or something.

Answer (score 0):

in firefox :

```
var mediaElement = document.getElementById('mediaElementID');  
mediaElement.seekable.start();  // Returns the starting time (in seconds)  
mediaElement.seekable.end();    // Returns the ending time (in seconds)  
mediaElement.currentTime = 122; // Seek to 122 seconds  
mediaElement.played.end();
```

Comment: The question is not about seeking

Answer (score 0):

For captions try using WebVTT. There's an in-depth tutorial on it here: [HTML5 Multimedia and Accessibility](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/an-in-depth-overview-of-html5-multimedia-and-accessibility/) and [WebVTT and Video Subtitles](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/05/html5/webvtt-and-video-subtitles). There are a number of JavaScript libraries out there that will help you with this, some are mentioned in the articles.